# ODrive mounting connectors

Tags: connector, motor-controller, mounting-holes

I have to connect motor voltage wires to an ODrive motor controller. I can't find 3-pin mounting connectors to solder to the controller that fit the configuration. Does anyone know what they are called?

It is rev c configuration in the link with three small holes that are the same size: [ODrive Configuration](https://odriverobotics.com/shop/odrive-pro)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are holes for ring terminals and fasteners (screw and nut).

(I think that the two small holes are just vias, not antirotation features.)

You may also be able to install a large screw-terminal block in there. If you tell us the pitch (center-to-center spacing of the holes) we can suggest one.